# How to read this JSON as an object? Gson

Tags: java, json, rest, get, gson

I have a decent amount of experience with REST and JSON, but I'm failing at coming up with a way to read  some JSON as a Java object.

The response is here: https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XBTCZEUR&interval=60

Notice how one of the names (the relevant data) is dependent on a query parameter. I'm not sure how to create a Java object for Gson to use for deserialization, as one of the variable names can change.

I thought that maybe using a JsonReader to read the response in a streaming fashion might work, but when  I do this I get a 403 error response.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can follow an aproach to read it in bean's format so that the bean contains all the elements (those can be found or cannot be fount in the JSON) also you json has many parameters so its better you use bean `http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=13e7c95e8439b49c20412204ecaa1c8e`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have exact knowledge regarding what the response will contain, you can always use an implementation of map class to pass on to gson, as I have tried to demonstrate in here :

```
public class RestResponse {

    private boolean success;
    private String errorDescription;
    private Map<String, Object> data;

    private static Gson GSON = new Gson();

    private RestResponse()
    {
        data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    private void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getErrorDescription() {
        return errorDescription;
    }

    private void setErrorDescription(String errorDescription) {
        this.errorDescription = errorDescription;
    }

    public Object getData(String... nestedKeys)
    {
        List<String> nestedKeysAsList = Arrays.asList(nestedKeys);
        return getData(nestedKeysAsList);
    }

    public Object getData(List<String> nestedKeys)
    {
        String firstKey = nestedKeys.get(0);
        if(!data.containsKey(firstKey))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key not found");

        Object mapValue = data.get(firstKey);

        if(!(mapValue instanceof Map))
            return mapValue;

        String finalKey = nestedKeys.get(nestedKeys.size()-1);
        if(nestedKeys.size() > 2)
        {
            for(String nextKey : nestedKeys.subList(1,nestedKeys.size()-1))
            {
                Map<String,Object> tempMap = (Map)mapValue;
                mapValue = tempMap.get(nextKey);
            }
        }

        Map<String,Object> tempMap = (Map)mapValue;
        return tempMap.get(finalKey);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    private void setData(Map<String, Object> map){
        this.data = map;
    }

    public static RestResponse createUnsuccessfulResponse(Exception e)
    {
        return createUnsuccessfulResponse(e.getMessage());
    }

    public static RestResponse createUnsuccessfulResponse(String reason)
    {
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        res.setSuccess(false);
        res.setErrorDescription(reason);

        return res;
    }

    public static RestResponse createSuccessfulResponse(String jsonString)
    {
        Map<String, Object> jsonToDataMap = GSON.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
        return createSuccessfulResponseByMap(jsonToDataMap);
    }

    private static RestResponse createSuccessfulResponseByMap(Map<String, Object> jsonToDataMap)
    {
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        res.setSuccess(true);
        res.setErrorDescription("Success");
        res.setData(jsonToDataMap);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Usage examples can be found over here :

https://github.com/cgunduz/btcenter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cemgunduz/utils/entity/RestResponse.java